# Kinect v2, Get the time a frame was captured

Tags: time, kinect

I want to know exactly when a frame was Captured on the Kinect v2. There is a RelativeTime property available with each frame for this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyframe.relativetime.aspx

Unfortunately this seems to be gibberish. Theres one comment on that page from another user to the same effect.
Here is an example console log of these values for a series of frames.

[image]

There seems to be many minutes between each frame, though in reality its running at about 60fps.

I'm going to just use the system time when the new frame event is called but I'm not sure if that is *exactly* the time when the frame was captured. This is a bit disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so It seems the timespan value is off by a factor of 10000

```
 Relativetime.TotalSeconds/10000
```

gives reasonable results. I dont know why though.. I'm using Unity so maybe there is a discrepancy between .net and mono.